# Html.forHtml issue in android

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Folks .

I am struggling with Html.ForHtml method that we have available in android

```
 String html =Html.fromHtml("&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Ahmed&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Aaaa&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;").toString();
```

The above variable html has "`<p>Ahmed</p><p>aaaa</p>`"

Now

```
newsDetail.loadData(html, "text/html; ", "charset=UTF-8");
```

newsDetail is a webview control . On the control i see exactly what was in the html string without being rendered . that is .`<p>Ahmed</p><p>aaaa</p>`

However if I do not use Html.ForHtml , and directly say .

```
newsDetail.loadData("<p>Ahmed</p><p>aaaa</p>", "text/html; ", "charset=UTF-8");
```

I have the correct rending on the webview , that is it shows me both of the words as a new paragraph .

Whats going on here ? . I actually have to make the first case work

Comment: Use `<p>Ahmed</p><p>aaaa</p>` into fromHtml

Comment: I don't think you have to format the `XML String` to `HTML`. `WebView` will automatically do it for you. Directly load that `XML String`  into `newsDetail`.

Comment: @PankajKumar I wont be able to do that , I just did that for testing it . I have received a string from a webservice with the lt and gt control characters

Comment: @Naddy . did that . it displays the lt and gt etc as is :S . It doesn't render them